# Editing MediaWiki Menus hosted on AWS

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mediawiki, google-developer-tools

i`m having a problem on the developing of my Wiki for my job, which is was created using MediaWiki.

The wiki is been hosted on AWS, and i`m using the virtual servers EC2.

I dont know if i`m using the right terms because i know nothing about programming but this job was given to me and i really have to make it work.

My problem is when i try to change the Menus (Navigation, Tools, etc..). I could change its color on the .css documents but trying to rewrite the name its been a huge problem.

[Image of what is happening here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD8TN.jpg)

The thing is that ">>" after the "Navigation" and "Tools" does not desapear, i have already accessed the mediawiki:sidebar but nothing changes. Also, there is no .css file that contains this code of the photo and there is no document on my wiki directory with this code.

I discovered that if i make any change on this code  of the photo it will solve my problem but i dont know how to find this document or even if it`s possible.

If i click "Source" on Crome developers tool, i can see the directory of my wiki and inside of it the directories "Skin/gumaxdd" and "Index.PHP", the second one contains the "Main_page" that has this code on, and the first have all the .css and scripts files of my wiki.

I try to use the FileZilla to find this directory on my wiki but i did not found, so i would like to ask if there is how to edit these codes and how do i do it?

Sorry if it is a simple question, but is taking me so much time, i don`t even know what to ask about it in order to solve my problem.

Thanks people. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, i cannot access this but i can access the "gumaxdd.php", there is the code i have to change.

But first, if i now nothing about coding, i just make that things i want on google inspect and copy the line that comprehends the category that changes are located.

then i go to mediawiki:commons.css and paste it there.

When i do it, the mediawiki already put that code on the format i must put on the gumaxdd.php file, then i have to copy this code.

After that you'll need only open the file, search for that category that comprehends my changes and paste the code.

And it is done, everything is done without too much understand of coding !